# Batch file for loop convert to another shell script 1

Tags: shell, batch-file, converters

Can anybody help in converting this batch file code to Unix Shellscript.

```
For %%f in (f\\*) do (
tshark -r %%f -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.seq -e tcp.ack -e tcp.window_size -e tcp.flags -e http.request.method -e http.response.code -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f> out\\%%f.csv
 )
goto :eof
```

Thanks,

#### Update

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising  44957 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47020.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising   6174 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47022.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising   6133 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47065.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising   6503 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47070.pcap
```

These are above my list of file names ..

If I run  this shell script for this one ... it is not working

```
for f in f/*; do
    tshark -r "$f" -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.seq -e tcp.ack -e tcp.window_size -e tcp.flags -e http.request.method -e http.response.code -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > out/"$f".csv
done
exit
```

Comment: I forwarded your other updates here. Please update your question with more information you can post including error messages, etc. You should also delete your answer as it wasn't an answer.

Comment: I think you're not running on a normal shell terminal and probably on an emulated one. My script can only run a normal shell and not on cmd.exe or anywhere sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show all messages after running this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
mkdir -p out
for f in f/*; do
    echo "Processing file $f."
    tshark -r "$f" -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.seq -e tcp.ack -e tcp.window_size -e tcp.flags -e http.request.method -e http.response.code -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > out/"${f##*/}".csv
done
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in f\\*; do
tshark -2 -r "$f" -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.seq -e tcp.ack -e tcp.window_size -e tcp.flags -e http.request.method -e http.response.code -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f> out/"$f".csv
done
exit
```

This is one which worked for me if you have following files

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising  44957 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47020.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising   6174 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47022.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising   6133 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47065.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravising ravising   6503 Aug 16 06:33 f\f.pcap.TCP_74-125-68-157_443_172-16-210-197_47070.pcap
```